# How to Read a file into a 2D Array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

So I have a file ( user.txt ) containing this

```
James, 10, Orange 
Andrew, 16, Yellow 
Graham, 23, Pink
```

I want to make it so I can **read the file into** a nested list so I will have

```
print(user[0][1])
#10
```

I attempted:

```
with open("user.txt") as file:
    user = [line.split(", ") for line in file.readlines()]

print(user[0][1])
```

however I get 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Hope someone can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: You aren't working with arrays, but with *lists*.

Comment: Use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

Comment: What happens when you `print(user)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file location") as file:
    user = [line.rstrip("\n").split(", ") for line in file]
```